# E value cutoff for RNASeq search

Tags: bioinformatics

I am trying to narrow down the possible search criteria from an RNASeq experiment. I already have the cds sequences so I took these and used Blast+ program to blast the data against itself to find sequences that were the same.

From what I have read the E Value is based on the database size. My database only has ~27,000 sequences in it, does this mean that only exceptionally low E values will be relevant to me? Are there any other criteria I should search for before writing the program to eliminate similar sequences?

Comment: What are you mapping to the database- RNAseq reads? How long is the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by an e-value or bitscore cutoff will give you possible homologs, but it sound like you want to remove redundant sequences. If you want to cluster and combine similar sequences to make a smaller database, you could just go via sequence identity using something like [CD-HIT](http://weizhongli-lab.org/cd-hit/). This, for example, is what's done to produce the [UniRef set from the UniProt database](http://www.uniprot.org/help/uniref).